# Master and Detail View from Zero

Tags: xcode, uitableview, detailview

Im new in Xcode and Im working on a simple project. Im using and empty application and I want to create an RSS reader.
The question is how can I create from zero a MasterView and Detail View? Which subclasses should I use? A UITableView for the Master?? and for the Detail View??
Is there is any examples please help.

Answer (score 0):

XCode has a master detail template when you create a new iOS project.  Just follow the wizard and it will generate the code for you.